# Is there a way to use a default export from another package in Gulp and retain task names in the output?

Tags: gulp

## Background

I'm using Gulp in multiple Git repositories to build NPM packages. I don't want the Gulp tasks duplicated across each repository so I created a separate package to store the common Gulp logic. I'm also using `@babel/preset-env` to transpile `gulpfile.babel.js` to be able to use ES2015.

## Code

`npm link` commands excluded for brevity.

```js
// babel.config.js from both packages
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current'
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

#### my-gulp-tasks package

```js
// index.js
import { series } from 'gulp';

export function clean (cb) {
  console.log('cleaned');
  cb();
}

export function build (cb) {
  console.log('built');
  cb();
}

export const defaultTask = series(clean, build);
```

```js
// gulpfile.babel.js
export { defaultTask as default } from '.';
```

#### my-other-lib package

```js
// babel-register.js
require('@babel/register')({
  ignore: [/node_modules\/(?!my-gulp-tasks)/]
});
```

```json
// .gulp.json
{
  "flags": {
    "require": [
      "./babel-register.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

```js
// gulpfile.js
export { defaultTask as default } from 'gulp-tasks';
```

## Expectation

Gulp in `my-gulp-tasks` logs the following (as expected):

```
Starting 'default'...
Starting 'clean'...
cleaned
Finished 'clean' after 1.98 ms
Starting 'build'...
built
Finished 'build' after 1.3 ms
Finished 'default' after 6.89 ms
```

However, Gulp in `my-other-lib` logs the following:

```
Starting 'default'...
cleaned
built
Finished 'default' after 9.21 ms
```

I'd think they should both log the same series task names when the same Gulp arguments are used (none in this case). I've also tried setting the `displayName` on the `clean` and `build` tasks but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

## Question

Is this a bug in Gulp or am I just missing some configuration? I assume it's related to transpilation but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, this seems to only happen when using `npm link`. I published the package containing the gulp tasks and the issue went away once I installed the version from the repository. Now I'm guessing this has to do with the `@babel/register` `ignore` regex I'm using. Nonetheless, I'm satisfied with it only working from the installed package since my primary concern was troubleshooting in a CI environment if a task fails.